# Error de encoding en mensaje de confirmación de pregunta duplicada

Tags: bug

Acepté una pregunta como duplicada en `es.meta` y en el mensaje de confirmación los caracteres con acento salen con su código de charset.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desconozco si este error aplica también para `es.so`.